# logout automatically in all tabs when logged out in one open tab with django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Is it possible to auto logout a user from all opened tabs(Popup window), if that user logoout from one of the open tab in the browser in django. If it is possible then How can I implement?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

if user logs out in one tab, django will delete the **login session**. so in the other tab if user refresh the page, django cant find the **login session** and make user anonymous. you dont need to do anything.
but if you want to logout user without refreshing the page, i dont think its possible

Answer (score 0):

like the User above me said, you dont have to implement this. If the User in a Tab logs out, he is logged out in every Tab. 
You can use stuff like "@login_required" to avoid some mistakes like the user can see your Dashboard when hes logged out. It works fine. You can also make a redirect to your login-page if the user is not logged in atm. I know this is not part of your question but if you try to figure out how django works it could be a nice tip for you x)

PS: 
If you want stuff like login_required look at Django auth.